# JS and CSS not showing up after DB migration

Tags: magento-1.7, css, js-css, skin

I am having issues with my CSS and JS files not loading on my site since I recently migrated my database. If you visit my site you'll see that in console it says: `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html`

https://www.dtacollectibles.com/

I updated the permissions for the `skin` and `media` directories to `777`
In the Admin I also set Merge CSS and Merge JS to **No** but it seems that they are still getting merged.

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove rel="stylesheet" from the  tag, this worked for me fine.